# How do I document PHPUnit Tests Results?

Tags: phpunit

Other than the use of --testdox for documenting, is there another way I can give a more detailed report for my PHPUnit tests?

Comment: The code of the tests should be self-explanatory. Even more, it should document the behaviour of the tested code (its public API, not its implementation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not a direct answer to your question but you could consider using a BDD framework like [Behat](http://behat.org/). The tests are written in plain human language so they express your system behaviour and can be read by non-technical people.

Example from [introducing BDD article](https://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/):

```
Story: Account Holder withdraws cash

As an Account Holder
I want to withdraw cash from an ATM
So that I can get money when the bank is closed

Scenario 1: Account has sufficient funds
Given the account balance is \$100
And the card is valid
And the machine contains enough money
When the Account Holder requests \$20
Then the ATM should dispense \$20
And the account balance should be \$80
And the card should be returned

Scenario 2: Account has insufficient funds
Given the account balance is \$10
And the card is valid
And the machine contains enough money
When the Account Holder requests \$20
Then the ATM should not dispense any money
And the ATM should say there are insufficient funds
And the account balance should be \$20
And the card should be returned

Scenario 3: Card has been disabled
Given the card is disabled
When the Account Holder requests \$20
Then the ATM should retain the card
And the ATM should say the card has been retained
```